# Multiple validation to same field in react final form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

Is there a way to add multiple validation to single field in `React Final Form`? Something like:

```
<Field
  name='email'
  label='email'
  validate={[emailValidator, emptyValidator}]
/>
```

There is similar type of validation in `redux-form`. Is it there a way to do this type of validation in `React Final Form`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide multiple validators to Field using helper function eg. `composeValidators`

```
const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required');
const mustBeNumber = value => (isNaN(value) ? 'Must be a number' : undefined);
const minValue = min => value =>
  isNaN(value) || value >= min ? undefined : `Should be greater than ${min}`;

const composeValidators = (...validators) => value =>
  validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined);
```

And use it like:

```
<Field 
name="age" 
validate={composeValidators(required, mustBeNumber, minValue(18))} 
/>
```

check official example here [Field-Level Validation](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/field-level-validation)